# XSL QUESTION: alternative method to count the number of lines or newline characters of an xml attribute

Tags: string, xslt, count, numbers, lines

I've scoured the internet to discover this method of finding the number of lines in an xml element.:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(@Example) - string-length(translate(@Example, '&#xa;', '')) &lt; 10">
```

In the example above, @Example is the element for which the number of lines is counted. I didn't like this code, however, because it automatically gets turn into this:

```
    <xsl:if test="string-length(@Example) - string-length(translate(@Example, ' 
', '')) &lt; 10">
```

You see, the code `&#xa;` gets turned into a literal blank line (which it represents but I don't want it to be a blank line). That above seems like bad coding style to me(if it isn't, please tell me), so I want an alternate way for finding the number of lines in @Example. Thank you.

Comment: You must edit your title. You are not dealing with elements but attributes. Also, as my last answer to you, you could do this with XSLT 2.0 (accessing unparsed document and ussing a regexp matching). But, full answer for XSLT 2.0 would need input sample and desired output.

Comment: Shoot, didn't know you commented. Sorry, I have no fundamental understanding of xsl or xml, so that stuff goes right over my head.. But I'll look into the xslt 2.0.

Comment: Good question (+1). I tried hard to find something better and I think I did -- have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**This style is probably closer to your preferences**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:variable name="vNL" select="'&#xA;'"/>

 <xsl:template match="t">
  <xsl:value-of select=
    "string-length(@Example)
    -
     string-length(translate(@Example, $vNL, ''))"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The NL constant is kept in a variable** and referencing this variable does not cause an editor to display a new line.

**Even the `$vNL` declaration can be cured of this problem** -- provided this is made into a global `<xsl:param>` and the value is provided by the external invoker of the transformation.

Comment: Yes. But as I answer previously, only new-line **character reference** in the input source will be keep into attribute value after normalization.

Comment: @Alejandro: Sorry, I completely lost you. Is there any problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification of my previous answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366181/sharepoint-designer-keeps-turning-xa-within-source-code-into-literal-new-line )

Running this stylesheet (same as Dimitre):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vNL" select="'&#xA;'"/>

 <xsl:template match="xsl:value-of">
  <xsl:value-of select=
    "string-length(@select)
    -
     string-length(translate(@select, $vNL, ''))"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With itself as input, output:

```
0
```

It only works with input like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vNL" select="'&#xA;'"/>

 <xsl:template match="xsl:value-of">
  <xsl:value-of select=
    "string-length(@select)&#xA;
    -&#xA;
     string-length(translate(@select, $vNL, ''))"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
2
```